# Filter R xts object to exclude a certain date

Tags: r, xts

I would like to subset an `xts` object to exclude a certain date.  Here is a simple example.

```
# This subsets to March 30, I would like to exclude that date instead
library(xts)
xts1 <- xts(x=1:10, order.by=as.Date('2018-03-31')-1:10)
xts1['2018-03-30']
```

These 2 lines work.

```
xts1[-which(index(xts1) == '2018-03-30')]
xts1[!(index(xts1) %in% as.Date('2018-03-30'))]
```

The second of the two above is preferable because it is robust to the date not existing in the `xts` object.  For example...

```
# returns empty xts
xts1[-which(index(xts1) == '1960-03-30')]

# returns full xts
xts1[!(index(xts1) %in% as.Date('1960-03-30'))]
```

It seems like there would be a less verbose and better practice way to do this such as the below (which do not work).

```
xts1[-'2018-03-30']
xts1[!'2018-03-30']
```

Is there a better way of doing this than the solutions I have? (i.e. `xts1[-which(index(xts1) == '2018-03-30')]`, `xts1[!(index(xts1) %in% as.Date('2018-03-30'))]`)

Comment: `xts1[index(xts1) != '2018-03-30']` also works, and is slightly simpler

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I can't comment because I have <50 reputation but I think the answer @AndrewGustar gave is the best one.

`which` returns a vector of indices where the logical test provided was satisfied in the object. To be more clear, if you run

```
> index(xts1) != '2018-03-30'
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

what you get back is a vector of boolean. Now if you feed this into the `which` function you get

```
> which(index(xts1) != '2018-03-30')
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

You can refer to `?which` but it essentially spits out the indices in `xts1` where the logical test was `TRUE`.

You can then use this vector of indices to select the data inside `xts1` with

```
xts1[which(index(xts1) != '2018-03-30')]
```

However, `xts` objects can also be sliced using simply the boolean vector. So you can just slice using a logical test and it works perfectly fine

```
> xts1[index(xts1) != '2018-03-30']
           [,1]
2018-03-21   10
2018-03-22    9
2018-03-23    8
2018-03-24    7
2018-03-25    6
2018-03-26    5
2018-03-27    4
2018-03-28    3
2018-03-29    2
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use set `which.i = TRUE` in `[.xts`, which will return the index locations instead of the subset of the xts object.

For example:

```
(rmrow <- xts1["2018-03-30", which.i = TRUE])
# [1] 10
(xts2 <- xts1[-rmrow, ])
#            [,1]
# 2018-03-21   10
# 2018-03-22    9
# 2018-03-23    8
# 2018-03-24    7
# 2018-03-25    6
# 2018-03-26    5
# 2018-03-27    4
# 2018-03-28    3
# 2018-03-29    2
```